# Set Position of Seekbar below an Image View

Tags: android, layout, imageview

Im quite new to android I have an Image view and a seekbar,the user is allowed to load image which is displayed in the image view,the seek bar should be just below the image view.I have the following code in Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp" 


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="clickme"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problems is when i load an Image of different size the seekbar is covered by the image view.I think i should resize the image or set some property of the imageview like 'Strech' in C# so that a proper layout is maintained.Can some one show me the right path

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

These properties in your imageview is causing the imageview to enlarge.

use `android:adjustViewBounds`

Comment: tried android:adjustViewBounds now the image covers up both the Slider and Button

Answer (score 0):

Change the alignment of the image view  as above the seekbar, something like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp" 
    />
```

In this way you force the image view to be always above the seek bar.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button"
            android:onClick="clickme"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note the `android:layout_gravity="center"`, and that I added a dummy View with a layout_weight so that it fills up the space above the Button; so the Button stays at the bottom.

UPDATE: updated the individual margins

Comment: Sorry, I needed to indent the first line to make the LinearLayout appear.

Comment: No,there is some problem,it kind of worked when i added an image first but at the beginning if no image is specified in the imagview then does not work

Comment: I meant did it work just by itself, without adding extra views to it or changing it. If it only doesn't work if you modify it then please post you modifications.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way will be:

```
  <Seekbar android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/YouImageViewID"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jus try RelativeLayout, here is partial code

```
    <RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
 >
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:src="@drawable/androidbiancheng"
  />
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
  />
 <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progressbar"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```